# Updating an Apple Watch's complication's content at midnight

Tags: apple-watch-complication, clockkit

I've add my complication entries and this all seems to work well - each complication entry is scheduled for midnight.

I'm testing the time change by setting my Mac's date to the following day where I'm expecting my complication to update to the next entry.

However, it only updates the entry when I open and close my app. I'm expecting to see it automatically change like the other standard complications do. Is this some behaviour I need to go out of my way to implement? I'd expect an automatic change as per the docs.

I've found the following:

> ClockKit begins displaying a timeline entry precisely at the time specified by the entry’s date property.

But surely this is a greater than check too? I tried setting it exactly to midnight but (surprisingly) this doesn't work either.

Any help is appreciated.

Additionally, I found the following regarding updating the timeline, but I would have thought this would be for changing the timeline entries as oppose to just refreshing the complication for the current timeline:

> During a background app refresh task. You can schedule background tasks to periodically update your watchOS content. This works best when your data changes at predictable times.

Answer (score 0):

The Watch Simulator appears to have some quirks around handling of times. In particular, it doesn’t seem to obey time changes on the underlying system until you relaunch it.

Relaunch the Simulator after changing the system clock and check on your Complication then. If you want to test the transition to the next day specifically, you can set the system time to 11:58 pm and wait for it to cut over.